# solving sub-query error ORA-01427 with join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, ora-01427

I have a small sub-query in a lengthy select statement and I'm out of ideas (I get the same ORA-01427 error whether I'm working with the entire select statement or if I segregate out the sub-query.  I have following:

```
NAME table
student_id_number field

TERM table
term_id field
student_id_number field

TEST view
test_id field
test_element field
student_id_number field
test_date field
score field
```

For a unique term_id value I want to select a score when the test_id field = A and the test_element field = COMP.  I realize that it's possible for there to be more than one valid combination of these elements per each unique term ID and student_id_number field, but the test_date field will still be unique for multiple rows and I suspect using a max(value) for score or test_date might get around the problem.  But I'm not certain how to do this.

Trying to insert ROWNUM = 1 in the where statement returns the first score from the table for all selected records.  Using max(score) in the select line returns the maximum score value for all selected records.

```
select
 a.term_id,
 a.student_id_number,
 (select ts.score
          from test_score ts
          left join term a on ts.student_id_number = a.student_id_number
          where ts.test_id = 'A' and ts.test_element = 'COMP') 
 from term a
 where a.term_id = '201701'
```

I want to see columns for term_id, student_id_number and score but I get the dreaded ORA-01427 error, perhaps (probably) because there may be multiple rows with matching student_id_number, test_id and test_element, however only the most recent score is relevant (or the highest score would also be relevant as opposed to the most recent score).  This is beyond the complexity of anything I've previously done and I'm not certain how (if) I can get around this problem.  Any help or advice for this inexperienced coder is appreciated.  Thanks.

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join in the subquery.  You need a *correlation* clause -- something that connects the result in the subquery to the row in the outer query:

```
select t.term_id, t.student_id_number,
      (select ts.score
       from test_score ts
       where ts.student_id_number = t.student_id_number and
             ts.test_id = 'A' and
             ts.test_element = 'COMP' and
             rownum = 1
      ) 
from term t
where t.term_id = '201701';
```

I added `WHERE rownum = 1` to limit the result set to one row.  You could also use aggregation -- `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, and `LISTAGG()` might all be appropriate.

Also, I changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the tables.  Arbitrary letters make the query harder to read.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon -- that did the trick for me.  I banged my head against the wall for quite some time on that one, simply because this isn't my area of expertise.  Thank goodness for forums like Stack Overflow and skilled people who are willing to share their knowledge with others.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation cause your subquery may return multiple rows that will create probelm

```
select
 a.term_id,
 a.student_id_number,
 (select sum(ts.score)
          from test_score ts
          left join term a1 on ts.student_id_number = a1.student_id_number
          where ts.test_id = 'A' and ts.test_element = 'COMP') 
 from term a
 where a.term_id = '201701'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need for a correlated subquery, using a `LEFT JOIN` without a `WHERE` clause would be enough:

```
select a.term_id, a.student_id_number, ts.score
  from test_score ts
  left join term a 
    on ts.student_id_number = a.student_id_number
   and ts.test_id = 'A' 
   and ts.test_element = 'COMP'
   and a.term_id = '201701'
   and to_char(ts.test_date,'yyyymm')=a.term_id;
```

and add `and to_char(ts.test_date,'yyyymm')=a.term_id` collation.

Comment: Thank you, Barbaros.  I will try this as well as I try to broaden my basic skillset.